# Problems caused by different syntax when writing tool libraries

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, npm, web

I wrote an npm tool (similar to the one in the `node_modules./bin` directory).
The tool is written in ts. The `import` syntax is used to import modules into the code. So I wrote `type: "module"` in `package. json`.

However, in the `. bin/cli. js` file, the `require` syntax is used. Only `type: "commonjs"` can use the following code.

```
#!/ usr/bin/env node
require('../dist/index.js')
```

How should we deal with this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [Creating ESM-based shell scripts for Unix and Windows with Node.js](https://2ality.com/2022/07/nodejs-esm-shell-scripts.html#running-hello.mjs-directly) blog post by Dr. Axel Rauschmayer, you should be able to rename your bin file from `cli.js` to `cli.mjs`:

```
#!/ usr/bin/env node
import '../dist/index.js';
```

I'd expect that nodejs *should* be then use the package.json `"type": "module"` value to treat your module as ESM after that.

You can then just run the bin file as usual:

```
$ ./bin/cli.mjs
```